# Set style of form label based on selection state using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, radio-button

I have a form with radio buttons, as in

```
<label for="challenge" class="fat">Challenge 
    <input type="radio" name="create-what" value="challenge" id="challenge">
</label>
<label for="team" class="fat">Team 
    <input type="radio" name="create-what" value="team" id="team">
</label>
```

Obviously, clicking the label selects the radio. What I need to do also is change the class of the label based on the selected state of the radio button. So, add a class "active" to the selected radio's label, and remove it if the radio is not selected.

I have many pairs like this, so I was looking for the most portable way.  Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: See below.  Also http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/GgqFD/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery is quite simple by monitoring the `change` event and toggling the class based on the `checked` state

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){

     $(this).parent().toggleClass('active', this.checked).siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

`toggleClass` allows a boolean for second argument to determine whether to add or remove. `this.checked` will be either tru or false;

If you need this to run on page load as well just trigger the `change` when page loads:

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){

     $(this).parent().toggleClass('active', this.checked).siblings().removeClass('active');
}).change();
```

Comment: It's highlighting, but is not "un" highlighting.  See http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/GgqFD/

Comment: ahhh was thinking about a checkbox... updated code in answer.  http://jsfiddle.net/GgqFD/2/

Comment: make sure all radio groups have some sort of wrapping element, so labels of 2 groups aren't siblings. If wrapper not viable can build a selector based on name attribute to find others in group

Comment: that did it.  thanks. I have each pair in a fieldset.  That should do it, no?